# Confusion on nested coalescing operator

Tags: swift, option-type

I came across this code snippet recently.

```
let s1: String?? = nil
(s1 ?? "inner") ?? "outer" // Prints inner





let st2: String?? = .some(nil)
(st2 ?? "inner") ?? "outer" // prints outer
```

Not sure why (`s2 ?? "inner"`) returning `nil`. Totally confused on this. Can some one please help me understand the reason.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially disregarding the combined use of the `nil` coalescing operator: when working (for some reason) with nested optional types, it can be helpful to explicitly type out the types (rather than using the common `?` syntactic sugar for each optional "level"). E.g.:

```
let s1: Optional<Optional<String>> = nil
     /* ^^^^^^^^^................^- 'nil' with regard to "outer" optional */

let s2: Optional<Optional<String>> = .some(nil)
     /* ^^^^^^^^^................^- the "outer" optional has value .some(...), i.e,
                                    not 'nil' which would be .none.
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^-the "inner" optional, on the other hand, has
                                  value 'nil' (.none) */
```

Using the explicitly typed nested optional (`String??`) and analysing the two different assignments as above, we can proceed evaluating the two combined `nil` coalescing operator calls on each instance. It becomes apparent that:

```
let foo1 = (s1 ?? "inner") ?? "outer" // equals "inner"
       /*   ^^- is 'nil', hence the call to 's1 ?? "inner" will coalesce
                to "inner", which is a concrete 'String' (literal), which
                means the second nil coalescing operator will not coelesce
                to "outer" */

let foo2 = (s2 ?? "inner") ?? "outer" // equals "outer"
       /*   ^^- is .some(...), hence the call to 's1 ?? "inner" will coalesce
                to _the concrete value wrapped in 's1'_; namely 'nil', due some, .some(nil).
                hence, (s1 ?? "inner") results in 'nil', whereafter the 2nd nil
                coalescing call, 'nil ?? "outer"', will naturally result in 'outer' */
```

The key to understanding the slightly trickier `s2` case is that applying the `nil` coalescing operator with a lhs (left hand side) that is `.some(...)` *will always result in the value wrapped by the* `.some(...)`, even if the wrapped value itself happens to be `nil` (or, `.none`).

```
Optional<SomeType>.some(someThing) ?? anotherThing
// -> someThing, even if this happens to be 'nil'
```

This is also quite apparent if we choose to take a look at [the stdlib implementation of the `nil` coalescing operator](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Optional.swift#L609):

```
public func ?? <T>(optional: T?, defaultValue: @autoclosure () throws -> T)
    rethrows -> T {
  switch optional {
  case .some(let value):
    // in your example (s2 and leftmost ?? call), 'T' is Optional<String>,
    // and 'value' will have the value 'nil' here (which is a valid return for 'T')
    return value 
  case .none:
    return try defaultValue()
  }
}
```

Comment: I think that there is a mistake in the second chunk of code, since both foo1 and foo2 are declared equally there. Shouldn't be "foo2 = (s2 ??..." ?

Comment: I'm glad to help!

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> let st2: String?? = .some(nil) 
> (st2 ?? "inner") ?? "outer" // prints outer
> ```
>
> Not sure why (s2 ?? "inner") returning nil

Because that is what you put there:

```
let st2: String?? = .some(nil)
                          ^^^
```

Compare:

```
let st2: String?? = .some("howdy")
(st2 ?? "inner") ?? "outer" // prints howdy
```